# How to have only cell with values and not "-"

Tags: excel

I have an excel column with values and "-", and I want to have only the number values in another column.

How can I do?
Here the column

[image]

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: I think the last one

Comment: Then `=FILTER(A:A,(A:A<>"-")*(A:A<>""))`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Select the respective column, then go to

Data Tab > Data Tools > Text to Columns

Delimited > click next > then check Other tab and enter "-"

then click next and click finish

finally "-" are disappeared